# Configure tugboat to use compressed SSH

Tags: ssh, digital-ocean

I am using tugboat to manage droplets from DigitalOcean.

One can use `tugboat ssh <NAME>` to ssh into a droplet.

With the standard SSH command, one can invoke compression with the `-C` flag:

```
ssh -C user@host
```

Is there a way to have tugboat compress its SSH stream?

Answer (score 0):

It looks in the tugboat source as though you can configure `~/.tugboat` to include an `ssh_opt` line, like so:

```
ssh:
  ssh_user: user
  ssh_key_path: "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
  ssh_port: '22'
  ssh_opts: '-C'
```

However, I can't tell whether or not this line is being used when the ssh command is invoked.